# vertx-redis-client -HSET command with complex JSON object

Tags: redis, quarkus, vert.x

I can't create an HSET Request when passing a Map as argument value :

```java
Map<String, Context> contextsMap = new HashMap();

Request contextRequest =
                    Request
                            .cmd(Command.HSET)
                            .arg("mykey")
                            .arg(JsonObject.mapFrom(contextsMap ))
                    ;
```

According to the Request.java vertx class, I got the following error : "Graph objects are not allowed as values, only simple types"

Why does vertx doesn't support it while quarkus does ?
I need to use vertx because I work in a batch mode.

How to create a HSET command when passing a map as arg value ?

Comment: use objectMapper (jackson) and serialize upfront is the solution

Comment: Quarkus has some advanced mapping functionality that Vert.x does not provide OOTB. So, you need to implement that yourself.